# get image with reactjs from mongodb via spring boot api

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Good Morning everybody.

I have an image stored in mongodb as bson binary. Something like this:

[image]

I have an spring boot api controler that returns it as a base64 string via:
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getImage().getData())

In the frontend there is a reactjs application that fetchs the jpeg image and stores it in a state variable:

```
 fetch(
        URL
    )
     .then((response) => {
      //  console.log("Response"+ response);
         return response.text();
      })
       .then((data) => {           
        const imageObjectURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ data;
        setImage(imageObjectURL);;
```

At the browser i am getting this:

And a broken image.

[image]

What i am doing wrong?